# Producing adjacency matrix for random connected graphs with at least one negative cost cycle

Tags: matrix, random, graph

How can I produce adjacency matrix for random connected graphs with at least one negative cost cycle? Such graphs are useful for testing the algorithms that find negative cost girth in a graph.
Thanks

Comment: I remember I did something like that as a student at university

Comment: Can you help me now?